# How to construct a Bitset from a vector of int

Tags: c++, bitset

I'm trying to construct a vector of bitset from an vector of vector of int which contains 0/1 values.

`vector < vector <int> > T1;
vector < bitset <1> > B1;`

i see that bitset stuctures don't accept push_back() method, so i'm wondring hom can i copy the values in T1 in B1 ?

Thanks

Comment: Using lots of 1-bit `bitset`s is a bit odd. Are you looking for something like Boost's `dynamic_bitset`?

Comment: You can construct a 1-bit `bitset` directly from an `int` value that is 0 or 1.